# Hide Column in GridView from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in my page that I have to set from the code behind (certain columns are not included sometimes), but one column contains hyperlinks. I am currently setting the gridview and hyperlink column in the .aspx page like this:

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server"  ID="GridView1" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Edit" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="Edit" />
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

I'm binding the rest of the data in the code behind:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;           
GridView1.DataBind();         
Page.DataBind();
```

The link column is showing up fine, and the links work as expected. However, the GridView that is created has the link column on the left, all of the columns that I want to show up, and then another column on the right that contains a string of the link, like this:

```
<a href='ForecastComments.aspx?zip=49905&date=1day'>Edit
```

Is there a way I can get rid of this column but still have my link column? I can't delete it from the table because I need access to it for the link column. I tried changing the code behind to this:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;           
GridView1.DataBind();            
this.GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = false;
Page.DataBind();
```

because the column I don't want showing is column 12, but the number of columns in the gridview is apparently only 1 (not sure why that is), so anyway, it didn't work. Bonus: I would rather have the link column on the right of the table, not the left--if anyone knows how to do that also, that'd be awesome.

Comment: well do this.. use the debugger.. when you step past this line `GridView1.DataSource = dt;` use the QuickWatch and click on the magnifying glass as tell us how many columns are coming back.. also columns in this case are `0` base not ``base`

Comment: @MethodMan The problem is, the only columns Gridview1.Columns is counting is explicitly declared columns. So, when I follow your suggestion and view it in the debugger, I can see all 12 columns of my table. However, I cannot access column 12 because it is not declared in the .aspx page. Since I need my columns to be autogenerated, I can't just use the method I was trying above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cells can be moved and/or deleted in the `RowDataBound` event of the GridView. You can set the event handler in the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

In code-behind, you define a variable to hold the index of the link column that you want to remove:

```
private int LinkColIndex;
```

and get its value from the DataTable before binding the data to the GridView:

```
LinkColIndex = dt.Columns["Edit"].Ordinal;
GridView1.DataSource = dt;           
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Finally, you process the cells for each row in the `RowDataBound` event handler:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(LinkColIndex);
    e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work; I put a breakpoint in the middle of that function while debugging, and it never even got there.

Comment: That code was tested, and works. I think that you did not set the event handler properly.

Comment: I added all of the code that you provided. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: If you set `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` in the markup, the event handler should trigger after you bind the data to the GridView (unless the data source has no record). You can check if you set another handler for the same event in code-behind (something like `GridView1.RowDataBound += ...`).

Comment: You're completely right; I'm sorry, I was changing it somewhere else because of old code that I had. Thanks so much!