# Add Div to GridView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to add a div inside the td of one column in my gridview table. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719965/dynamically-change-the-class-of-a-div-nested-in-a-gridview-item-template-from-co) that is similar to what I am trying to do, but the answer was not thorough enough for me to make it work how I want. Basically, I am generating the data for my gridview automatically from a DataTable dt:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The html for the gridview is here:

```
<div class="gridTable" style="width:100%">
  <asp:GridView runat="server"  ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="insideDiv" runat="server"></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>           
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

I want there to be an internal div on the column titled "Comments". I got this far with my OnRowDataBound function:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("insideDiv");

        }
}
```

But I am unsure how to go from here. What I need is to be able to access the div in my css, because that column is formatted differently than the others.

Comment: I don't think you can have a <div> tag run at server. You could use `<asp:Literal id="lit0" runat="server" />` From there, you can add and set the <div> tags, text, and such like.

Comment: @Sometowngeek Yes, it can run at server. That's what [HtmlGenericControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the content of the div with a data binding expression, and set a class attribute that you will refer to in your CSS styles. Assuming that the content is given by the `Comments` field of the data source, it could look like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="innerDiv" >
            <%# Eval("Comments") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can then add the style definition for the `innerDiv` class:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .innerDiv
    {
        ...
    }
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

In your comment (below), you mention that you would prefer to replace the content of the auto-generated column rather than add a column with a TemplateField. For that, you can use a technique similar to the one we used in [Hide Column in GridView from Code Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132227/hide-column-in-gridview-from-code-behind).

Define a variable for the column index of the `Comments` field:

```
private int commentsColIndex;
```

Get its value form the DataTable:

```
commentsColIndex = dt.Columns["Comments"].Ordinal;
GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Replace its content by a div element in the `RowDataBound` event handler, and set the `class` attribute of the div element:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell commentsCell = e.Row.Cells[commentsColIndex];
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
        div.Attributes.Add("class", "innerDiv");
        div.InnerHtml = commentsCell.Text;
        commentsCell.Text = string.Empty;
        commentsCell.Controls.Add(div);
    }
    ...
}
```

N.B. You may have to add an offset to `commentsColIndex` if some other cells are moved or deleted in the row.

Comment: Would I need to do anything with the GridView1_RowDataBound function?

Comment: If you only want to fill the div with the `Comments` field value and set a class style, the code above should be enough. That's why I did not show the `id` and the `runat="server"` attributes.

Comment: When I add that to my code, it creates another column that it puts the Comments field value in, at the beginning of my table. When I inspect the page, I see that the each cell is inside the innerDiv div. However, it still keeps the Comments column at the end of the table as well, and that one is not inside the div. Is there a way to add the div to my existing column? The current solution seems to be adding another column with the div and the data, instead of just adding the div to the existing column.

Comment: Yes, adding a TemplateField prepends a column to the "auto-generated" ones. There is a way to modify the generated column, which would use a similar technique as in [your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132227/hide-column-in-gridview-from-code-behind). I will have to update my answer but it will not be immediately (in about an hour, if nobody else answered before).

Comment: I added the new code to my answer. By the way, I assume that you really need to work with auto-generated columns. If not, setting `AutoGenerateColumn="false"` and defining the columns explicitly in the markup would make things much easier.

Comment: I wish you were right because it would be easier but actually the columns are different depending on other circumstances in the code behind so I do need them to be auto-generated. Thanks so much for updating your answer; that's exactly what I needed.